# Ordinal vs. Cardinal $0$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, cardinals, ordinals

From my files ...
$1, 2, 3, ...$ are *cardinals*, they *count* as in $9$ trucks, $12$ voles, etc.

First ($1^{st}$), Second ($2^{nd}$), etc. are *ordinals*, they're used to *order* stuff.

Now, I've heard of the $0^{th}$ law of thermodynamics, but even the late great Isaac Newton stated his $3$ laws as $1^{st}, 2^{nd}, 3^{rd}$.

In the world of sports, it's the same: $1^{st}, 2^{nd}, 3^{rd}$.

Even in math, with sequences (arithmetic/geometric/etc.), we speak of $T_1$ (first term), $T_2$ (second term), so on.

Why is it, o mathematician, that $0$ makes *less*/$0$ sense as an *ordinal* than as a *cardinal*?

I suppose we could say that *ordinals* have *existential import* i.e. it implies *esse* (being) while *cardinals* do not. $0$ is associated/mapped with/to *nonbeing* or *nonexistence*.

Answer (score 3):

We do treat $0$ as an ordinal when appropriate.
Think about the terms in a power series indexed by their degree. The $0$th term is the constant term.

In computer science the most useful default for arrays, vectors, sequences is to start with the $0$th term. So a sequence of (cardinal) length $4$ has terms up to the (ordinal) $3$rd.

Comment: That's nice to know. However, if we count from $0$ we'd always have to make a "correction" e.g. if Newton's laws were $0^{th}, 1^{st}, 2^{nd}$ and we were asked *how many* Newtonian laws of motion are there? $2^{nd}$ *doesn't match* with $3$, the answer to that question.

Comment: Sometimes two conventions cause momentary confusion. Programs often suffer "off by one" errors. Turns out they are less likely with $0 indexing.